# When to use a 2 sided 2 sample t test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, sample

When is a scenario that you would use a 2 sample, 2 sided t-test? I am currently trying to solve a problem and i know i need a 2 sample t test because im comparing the means of 2 data sets but not sure about 2 sided?

Answer (score 1):

The two sided two sample t-test is used to

> compare the means of two groups under the assumption that both samples are random, independent and come from a normally distributed population with unknown, but equal variances.

Here are some possible examples:

- Is there a difference in the performance in a Math test? The students from Teacher A or from Teacher B
- Is there a difference in salary between people from village A or people from village B?
- Is there a significant difference in the weight between people who eat vegetables daily and people who don't eat vegeatables on a daily basis.